# Angular Node string parameter escaping error

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a meanjs app. In my html, I have the following

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addMember({{user._id}});" >
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

The HTML renders just fine (see below)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addMember(55a897dfad783baa677e1326);" >
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

But it does get the following error in the console

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'user._id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 13 of the expression [addMember({{user._id}});] starting at [user._id}});].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$parse/syntax?p0=user._id&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=13&p3=addMember(%7B%7Buser._id%7D%7D)%3B&p4=user._id%7D%7D)%3B
```

If I add single quote around the method

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addMember('{{user._id}}');" >
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Everything is rendered fine in HTML, no errors in the console but once the method is called (in the controller)

```
    $scope.addMember = function(userid) {
        console.log(userid);
    };
```

it outputs the string literal `{{user._id}}` instead of `55a897dfad783baa677e1326`

What do am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `ng-click` passing the user.id without `{{ }}`. `ng-click="addMember(user._id);"`

Comment: gah! thanks. that was it. silly me. if you want to move your comment to the answer, i can give you credit for it

Comment: I moved it to answer. Thx Ervin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-click` passing the `user.id` without `{{ }}`. Like `ng-click="addMember(user._id);`